# Installing a secondary drive in CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, mount, hard-disk

I am new to Linux and CentOS so I may not be sure of the exact question to ask.  It may be best for me to tell you what I have done.  I installed a secondary 500gb HD to use for file share storage.  I have partitioned, formatted, and mounted according to many different websites' instructions.  I used this command to format:

```
mkfs.ext4 -L /Filesystem2 /dev/sdb1
```

This caused the new file system to be displayed in "Computer" via the GUI.  However, it was inaccessible.  Once I mounted it, I can access it from the CLI and the GUI, but it no longer shows up in "Computer".  Using the GUI as a user, I have to search to find the mounted drive.  It does not appear anywhere.  I would like to have it like Windows where it appears as a secondary drive.  I don't know how to do this or the Linux terminology for it.

Comment: Several questions arise: Which GUI do you use? How and where do you mount it? Is it not always mounted at the same path?

Comment: I am using GNOME.  Commands one by one as root:

Comment: Better edit your question than explain this in comments.

Comment: I am using GNOME.  Commands one by one as root: 1) `mkfs.ext4 -L /Filesystem2 /dev/sdb1` -> Visible in GNOME/Computer as user but inaccessible.  2) `mkdir /Filesystem2` 3) `mount /dev/sdb1 /Filesystem2` -> Disappeared in GNOME/Computer as user, can find Filesystem2 via search but I have no idea where it is or how to access it without searching.  I'd rather it be another Filesystem drive in Computer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You should easily find `/Filesystem2` with every file manager tool. And you can create symlinks to this path wherever you prefer to see them. "It's not a bug it's a feature" – "Computer" is supposed to show only unmounted volumes. I don't know if that can be configured but should not be necessary.

Comment: In CLI I `su - user`, `cd /`, then `vdir' and `Filesystem2` is there.  I can also `cd Filesystem2` and access it.  I still cannot see it in GNOME.  Should I edit the `/etc/fstab' to automount then restart to see if it corrects the issue?

Comment: I am sure you can already see it in GNOME; just not where you expect it. I didn't even know `vdir`... You can put a symlink in your $HOME directory with this command (no `su` required): `cd` into the directory in which you want to see the new disk. `ln -s /Filesystem2` Then a "directory" with the name "Filesystem2" should appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the disk mounted automatically. You need an entry in `/etc/fstab` for this. You can do this with any editor (just copy another line and modify it) but there certainly is a distro tool for the job (I don't know CentOS, maybe someone else can add this information).

If you use an editor then first make a backup of the file and after the modificationtry to mount the partition from a shell (as root if necessary) with the command `mount /dev/sdb1` (if `/dev/sdb1` is the device identification you have used in fstab) before you reboot. Because if you have created an error in the file your system will probably not boot any more.

Comment: He gave the filesystem a label (hint: `-L /Filesystem2`). It is best to use that for setting up his fstab, since the entry in /dev/ can change based on various things.

Comment: I set the disk to mount automatically.  After reboot, the user account gets a black screen when attempting to log in via VNC to GNOME.  I end up having to force quit the VNC client on my local Windows machine.  I can log in via VNC to GNOME as root (not recommended).  PuTTY works fine as any user.  Could some update have causes this???

Comment: @Joshua Volume mounting should not be related to VNC access at all. Can you login locally yet (as a user)? User login fails e.g. if your $HOME directory isn't available. But adding a volume should not affect that. What do you get as root with `ls ~user`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging  - I think the issue was when I edited the `/etc/fstab` to auto mount.  The `/dev/sdb1` has a label of `/Filesystem2` and I auto mounted it to a folder named `/Filesystem2`.  I created a new folder `/drive2` and edited the `/etc/fstab` to mount `/dev/sdb1` to it and now I have access via VNC again.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - Once `/etc/fstab` was edited and system rebooted, it works as you described in your answer.  Now, do i use `chmod` to give users access to the new mounted drive?

Comment: @Joshua `chmod`, `chown`, `chgrp` and `setfacl`.